# Breakdown of Azure VPN Users

Tags: azure, vpn, gateway

Recently had a local DB transitioned to Azure since we're working remotely. Works great, but there was no idle timeout set on the VPN, so people remained connected for as long as their laptops were turned on. Billing was crazy. Like $6 a day. I manually changed the idle timeout on PCs and laptops and thought that the issue was resolved, but it still looks like someone is connected all the time. I've been trying to find a way to see who that might be, but I don't know where to look in Azure.

I'd like to see a breakdown of who accessed it and for how long, but I haven't found anything yet. I see billing graphs and I found a P2S graph, but I can't drill down to see who specifically connected, for how long they were connected, or if anyone is currently connected. Ideas? I'm not paying for technical support, so thought I would ask here.

[top services by cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0mVl.png)

[P2S Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG6XW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... It looks like the guy that transitioned it opted for the VpnGw1, which is roughly $138 per month. Going to see if they can use the Basic VPN gateway type.

More info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/

Also, there is a P2S monitoring page where you can see who is connected, how long (in seconds) they have been connected, and what their IP is. So that's what I was looking for.

[VPN Gateway Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPGQC.jpg)
[P2S Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Sco.jpg)